# android java: foreach through json array returning values?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, for-loop

I'm having trouble doing a for each loop in my java code. I can get single json results, but how do I use a for each loop in this code?

Can someone help me?

```
public JSONObject feedTimeline(String username) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException{
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
    url.append(username);

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
    int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if(status == 200){
        HttpEntity e = response.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
        JSONArray timeline = new JSONArray(data);
        for (int i = 0; i < timeline.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject value= timeline.getJSONObject(i); //no error if this i is 0 and without for each loop
        return value; //getting errors because of this return tweets
        }


    }else{
        Toast.makeText(Feed.this,"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        return null;
    }
}


public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            json = feedTimeline("name");
            return json.getString(params[0]); //this would need to change I assume?
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I'm getting an error for JSONObject feedTimeline... if I have the for loop. but if I take that for loop out, and instead of having that `i` in `JSONObject value = timeline.getJSONObject(i)` and having a numberical value like `0` or `1`, then it does output.

Also, I believe in class Read, `return json.getString(params[0])` would also need to be worked in as for loop? I'm just really new to JAVA and I'm trying to learn everything on my own.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: String value = timeline.getJSONString("Your String Name")

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, I'm still a little new to Java, can you explain to me what you mean?

Comment: I'm getting twitter information so its just `public static String URL = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=";`

Comment: post your error i will see tomorrow....

Comment: There's an error on the `public JSONObject feedTimeline(String username)...` line, and it just says this method should return a result of type JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

```
    public JSONObject feedTimeline(String username) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException{
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
        url.append(username);

        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if(status == 200){
            HttpEntity e = response.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
            JSONArray timeline = new JSONArray(data);
            for (int i = 0; i < timeline.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject value= timeline.getJSONObject(i); //no error if this i is 0 and without for each loop
            return value; //getting errors because of this return tweets
            }


        }else{
            Toast.makeText(Feed.this,"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);      
        }
// changed the position of return statement. This should work now.
          return null;
    }
```